# Convert U8_C4 to CV_32FC1

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm getting a depth image 4 Channel Unsigned, and I would like to convert it to 32F_C1
so that I can use the addWeighed function.

I tried  the following code but I get access violation in addWeight function

```
           Mat depth_image_zed(new_width, new_height, MAT_TYPE::U8_C4);
           cv::Mat depth_image_ocv = slMat2cvMat(depth_image_zed);
           zed.retrieveMeasure(depth_image_zed, MEASURE::DEPTH, MEM::CPU, new_image_size);
           cv::Mat last_image(depth_image_ocv.rows, depth_image_ocv.cols, CV_32FC1);
           cv::Mat depth_clone = depth_image_ocv.clone();

           cv::Mat u16Image;
           depth_clone.convertTo(u16Image, CV_32FC1, 255.0); // no scaling factor, keep values "as is" !
 

            cv::Mat result;
            double factor = 0.19;
            cv::addWeighted(u16Image, 1.0 - factor, last_image, factor, 0.0, result);
            last_image = result.clone();

            cv::Mat ucharMatScaled;
            cv::Mat final_depth = result.clone();
            // scale values from 0..1 to 0..255
            final_depth.convertTo(ucharMatScaled, CV_8UC1, 255, 0);

            cv::imshow("original depth", depth_image_ocv);
            cv::imshow("filtered depth", final_depth);

            key = cv::waitKey(1);
```

Comment: `last_image` is not declared anywhere.  How did this code compile?

Comment: cv::Mat last_image(depth_image_ocv.rows, depth_image_ocv.cols, CV_32FC1);

Comment: I don't understand how you convert the `CV_U8C4` to `CV_32FC1`.  I'm not sure how the `convertTo` method would handle the multiple channels.  What is expected to happen?

Comment: @rayryeng maybe I'm wrong, can you tell me how would I convert U8C4 to CV_32FC1

Comment: The documentation for `convertTo` requires that the number of input channels and output channels need to be the same.  Your use of `convertTo` is unsupported - https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto.  What do you *expect* to happen when you go from 4 channels to 1?

Comment: @rayryeng I wanna do addWeight and it seems it needs one channel

Comment: That makes no sense to me.  Can you tell me what you're trying to accomplish with `addWeighted` instead?  This sounds like a XY Problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223966/discussion-between-ahmed-saleh-and-rayryeng).